# How to access multiple webserver pages over same wifi netwok

Tags: html, raspberry-pi

I have a little question .I have pi zero w and pi 3, I have created both as a webserver

1. pi zero w(webserver) example ip : 192.168.43.29
   webpages in server
   a.) index.html
   b.) temprature.html
2. pi 3(webserver) example ip " 192.168.43.39
   webpages in server
   c.) index.html
   d.) camera.html

here both webserver share same wifi network called" SAMBA" and the question is how can i access pi 3 server pages from pi zero w webserver over same wifi network.I tried from pi zero w to access pi 3 page

```
<a href="192.168.43.39/camera.html">Pi 3 </a>
```

but the output becomes :

```
192.168.43.29/192.168.43.39/camera.html
```

and lastly unable to access Pi 3 web pages.

Any help would be appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You might want to add http:// to the url...